# Are ASP.NET websites already multithreaded considering scalability on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

This comes in reference to another question [how does windows azure platform scale for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850714/how-does-windows-azure-platform-scale-for-my-app) stating only multithreaded applications would benefit from multi-core architecture.

My question is that as ASP.NET/IIS (or any other web application and web server) is basically multi-threaded will it not take the advantage of multi-cores?

Assuming the site is a simple web application with some logic that is executed on page display without explicit multithreading implementation.

I believe it is for the console applications or schedules only that require multithreaded programming implemented for it to take advantage of multi cores, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS by design implementation takes full advantage of all available to the OS CPU cores. However it is really application specific to decide which VM size to choose. I barely see anything larger than Medium being used for a **Web Role**!

The most common case is to use Small VM for a Web Role and scale out to multiple instances when unnecessary. And I always advise customers to start with a Small VM, do some performance/load testing while closely monitoring the VM to assess the need for a larger one (if any). From resilience point of view, as well as durability, and in many cases even performance, it is much better to rely on 4 Small VMs, rather than 1 Large!

Keep in mind that it is always easier, and cost-wise to scale with a smaller step (1 or 2 CPU Cores at once, meaning Small or Medium VM).

Comment: Thank you, that clears my doubt for a web server will take advantage by itself for really simplistic web sites. Any other complex processing and communication is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many business requirements existing in this world that require multi-thread on web application such as generate data and insert it to DB, export excel via AJAX... With a small VM and a minimum RAM with powerful core, if you don't manage your logic well and take advantage of hardware, your RAM would run out shortly.